# Cancel NSOperation in for loop?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsoperation, nsoperationqueue

I am trying to implement search on a background thread using `NSOperation` on `iOS`. I didn't want to subclass `NSOperation` so this is what I'm doing:

```
[searchQueue cancelAllOperations];
NSInvocationOperation *op = [[NSInvocationOperation alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                                  elector:@selector(filterContentForSearchText:)
                                                                   object:self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.text];
[searchQueue addOperation:op];
[op release];
```

The search method includes a for loop that checks whether what is being searched is in an array. Now when I cancel the `NSOperation` by calling `cancelAllOperations`, the for loop continues to run through the array. I would like to prevent this and was wondering whether it is legit to call this from within the for loop:

```
if ([[[searchQueue operations] objectAtIndex:0] isCancelled]) {
    [tmp_array release];   // tmp_array is used to hold temporary results
    [pool drain];          // pool is my autorelease pool
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One of the reasons to subclass `NSOperation` is to implement proper cancellation. You could do your approach, but it violates several good design principles. Basically, since cancellation requires the cooperation of the operation itself, `NSInvocationOperation` isn't built to cancel the invocation while it's already executing (though it can be successfully cancelled *before* it starts executing), as the running method shouldn't know anything about how it's called.

Instead, if you subclass `NSOperation`, you can put most of this functionality into the `main` method very easily:

```
@implementation MyOperation
- (void)main {
    if ([self isCancelled])
        return;

    for (...) {
        // do stuff

        if ([self isCancelled]) {
            [tmp_array release];
            return;
        }
    }
}

@end
```

Note also that you don't have to maintain your own autorelease pool with such an implementation.