# Best way to deal with a change in internet connection with HTTP networking

Tags: ios, objective-c, networking, httprequest, nsoperation

Normally, in my iOS Applications that use quite a lot of HTTP requests to communicate with the server, I add an NSBlockOperation to the app's global NSOperationQueue, and then suspend and enable the queue when the application detects a change in internet connection status thus saving any requests currently in the queue until the queue is unsuspended. However, I am not completely sure that in this way, any operations that are currently running will be stopped, and then re-added to the top of the queue.

My question is: are there any better ways to deal with a change in the network status when you are working with HTTP Requests to a remote server i.e. in pausing, resuming, cancelling requests etc...

Comment: The easist way, which is also most used and sufficient is to ignore the issue. Create requests, send them to the server and if the connection fails, display an error to the user. Nothing more. You can retry a connection when it fails but I wouldn't recommend to do it more than once for a request.

Comment: @Sulthan alternatively, what if the requests were internal e.g. analytics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Reachability](https://github.com/tonymillion/Reachability) class to detect when network status changes to avoid sending requests. This is based on, and updated from, some [sample code provided by Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html). This will let you know when the internet connection changes without polling.

As far as I know this is the best way to detect network availability. You'll get an instant notification when the network becomes available again. I believe it even tells you what kind of connection is available (WiFi or Cellular).

If the connection drops while making the request, you'll have to handle that condition as you currently are.

Answer (score 0):

Just my thoughts - you should add cancellation to your operations(manually) [like here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4492811/cancel-nsoperation-in-for-loop). When you detect network status changes(no connection), you can cancel current operations, pause queue, notify some manager so it can reschedule operations. When network becomes available, resume queue.

Comment: That's what I'm doing at the moment.

Comment: It's not clear from your question if you've added cancellation mechanism to your operations. When you suspend queue already running operations are not affected by default.

Comment: Ah, I see. So to make it clearer, the running operations should be tracked, and cancelled when there is a change in the internet connection, and then re-added to the beginning of the queue to be then sent again once there is available internet connection?

Comment: Yes. I'm not sure if you can reschedule operation from itself(I think it can be done with [NSOperationQueue currentQueue] addOperation:self], but never tried this myself, so don't know what it'll lead to). So suspend queue(to prevent it from starting new operations), cancel and reschedule running operations when connection is lost(queue is suspended, so it'll not fire new ops). Resume when connection appears.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'm afraid that I can't accept this as it doesn't actually answer my question, it just refers to how it can be improved.

Comment: Yes, I know. Hope it helps anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Transactions are just for this purpose. You need to make your ws calls *atomic*, that is, you start a transaction, make your call, get the response and commit the transaction. Then you can be sure that your task is completed.

In other case, you are again starting a transaction, making your ws call, ws call fails and you can' t get response, for whatever reason, and you rollback your transaction and log/report this situation. You just need to make sure if you really can' t afford missing ws calls.

Answer (score 0):

As Luke suggests, [Apple  sample](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) is best to handle this. But I would also like to address your need for change detection in network connection. This is handled by observing the notification named kReachabilityChangedNotification.

In other words, your view controller or delegate code must have following piece in order to handle network reachability (read "connectivity") changes:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver: self selector: @selector(reachabilityChanged:) name: kReachabilityChangedNotification object: nil];
```

And

```
//Called by Reachability whenever status changes.    
- (void) reachabilityChanged: (NSNotification* )note    
{    
      Reachability* curReach = [note object];        
      //TODO: Your specific handling.
}
```